# php loop to pull json data fields

Tags: php

Hello everyone and thanks for your time. I am trying to set up a loop to pull specific fields from a json api feed. The json feed can be seen here:

https://uysmiami.com/search/api_server_custom.php

I am trying to set up a loop to grab data from specific fields from the feed but with my limited php am grabbing other stuff as well. The results of my loop are can be seen at:

http://uysmiami.com/search/stevetest.php

the code I'm using is:

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('https://api.iyba.pro/vessel?key=95d30b94b3a7e8b8c2df379fb00816960f86e203&id=80393');
$data = json_decode($json,true );
foreach($data as $vdata)
{  foreach($vdata as $number){
echo "Name: ".$number['ListingOwnerName']."<br />";
} }
?>
```

how can I pull the fields I want and not the first two and last 4 lines of meaningless stuff?

Thanks again.

Comment: We get an error, and also I would recommend hiding keys from the public's eye. And please post the results from the API call and results versus a link which can be changed or go down over time, as this post stays up

Comment: sorry, i changed the link to view the json data. it's ok to leave the key as the raw feed has to be pulled from pre-approved IP's and the results of the api call are very long. Please let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got your desired results doing something like this:

```
$dataFromUrl = file_get_contents( 'https://uysmiami.com/search/api_server_custom.php' );
$dataEn = json_decode( $dataFromUrl, TRUE );
foreach( $dataEn['V-Data'] as  $vData )
{
    if ( isset( $vData['ListingOwnerName'] ) )
    {
        echo "Name: " . $vData['ListingOwnerName'] . "<br />";
    }
}
```

I am not sure if you need to loop through more things which is why you nested another loop, but for the V-Data array from the API shown, that got all the names without any numbers.

Comment: yah i'll want to eventually pull out more data, so i will have to drop the if statement, but i think this will at least get me going in the right direction :) thank you kindly!